# How to properly set points to polygon PostGis?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, polygon, psql

How to properly set points to `Polygon` i'm trying

```
  INSERT INTO "geo"("geometry")VALUES(ST_AsHEXEWKB(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((50.1033 26.4344,49.75 24,50.1033 26.4344))',4326)));
```

but had error: `<-- parse error at position 57 within geometry`;

when i set points from example all works. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got your polygon vertices coordinates, you may simply do:
`INSERT INTO {yourTableName} ({yourGeometryColumnName}) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(({x1} {y1}, {x2} {y2}, ...))'))`

Comment: If you wish to specify SRID explicitly, for some reason, you may feed `st_geomfromtext()` with second argument in decimal format (like, 4326)

Comment: with this parameters (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(***50.1033 26.4344, 49.75 24, 50.1033 26.4344***)', 4326)) don't work

Comment: my fault, `select ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((50.1033 26.4344, 49.75 24, 50.1033 26.4344, 50.1033 26.4344))', 4326)` should work, you should pay attention to double-brackets and last point, enclosing the polygon

Comment: ...if there're holes in your polygon, they have to be described as another set of points within `POLYGON((...),(...))`